# A way to access loop index from Django formset loop?

Tags: python, django

In Django framework templates you can loop through a formset like so:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to access the index of the loop? Perhaps something like this:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form }}
    {{ form.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which should render 0, 1, 2,... prior to each form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with any other loop in a Django template, you can use `{{ forloop.counter }}`.

Answer (score 0):

kinda late, but if you want 0-indexed rather than 1-indexed, use forloop.counter0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).